# Apply changes with binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am searching on how to firechange to an input field after applying changes using code. Here is the code:

```
Otable.getModel().setProperty("/Products(1)/Price",29)
```

[image]

How can i fire the change to the input field?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified the correct binding mode from model to view (one-way or two-way should work in this case) and bound the value of your input field to the property in the model, it should update automatically and you shouldn't have to fire any change to the input field manually.
If you implemented the data binding correctly, a change in the model should reflect to the input field and vice versa.

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
    value: "{/value}" // path to the property here
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkLtqa5p/
and also at this tutorial regarding data binding here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c.html